# Application overhead design decision: store needed value on database row or find it dynamically in queryset

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I'm developing a simple price tracker application. I'm a bit new to web application design and could use an experienced opinion here. My application pulls price points for hundreds of thousand of products per day by unique product SKU.

For each SKU I want to be able to show:

- All time high price
- All time low price
- Average price

When my API writes a new SKU price to the database I am able to figure out these three values and write them to the latest/current price row. Is this a better design decision than say using a Django Queryset in my View to query for and/or calculate and display them?

EDIT:

Sure, I'm currently feeding them to a Django Class Based View with `def get_context_data`.

```
context['high_price'] = prices.order_by('price').last()
context['low_price'] = prices.order_by('-price').last()
context['avg_price'] = prices.aggregate(average=Avg('price'))
```

Note that I am not using aggregate MIN/MAX as I need the date with each price as well so I need to entire price row (Price model is structured in columns of 'Date of Price' and 'Price').

Original question still stands. Should I Queryset this or write the high/low/average each time I bring in a new price? Here's how I could do that (example for highest all time price):

```
if product.high_price is None or (price.value is not None and price.value >= product.high_price.value):
            product.high_price = price
```

Comment: can you share the code, you can use Aggregation in django for AVG, SUM

Comment: Sure, edited the OP.

Comment: What is your criteria? Is this a performance bottleneck? Have you tried benchmarking it? Django debug toolbar can be used to inspect and profile database queries, https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Using a queryset for this should be fast, provided you have an index.  It would be interesting to benchmark what you have, then in your model, add index and repeat.  eg.

```
  price = models.DecimalField(db_index=True)
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_index

Calculating the average will be the slow one and it might be worth have a job that calculates the average and stores it somewhere.  You can use celery/redis to do this in the background or do it once when you pull the data in, depending on your setup.